# Solve $z+\sin{z}=i$

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

How can I find how many solutions following equation have?

$$z+\sin{z}=i$$

I can make substitution $z=it$ and get

$$t+\sinh{t}=1$$

which has one real solution $t\approx0.4900730685$ thus $z\approx0.4900730685i$.

However with Mathematica I found more solutions, some of them:
$$z\approx4.440301668+2.209373901i$$
$$z\approx-4.007976440-2.344091437i$$

And if there is infinitely many roots, is it possible to write formula for other roots using only first root I found?

Comment: I would rewrite as $2iz + e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 2$ i.e. $2(w - 1) + e^w - e^{-w} = 0$ for $w=iz$

Comment: Using $(x,y)=(\Re z,\Im z)$, one gets the system $$x+\sin x\cosh y=0,\qquad y+\cos x\sinh y=1,$$ involving only real valued quantities. If $x=0$ one gets your first root, otherwise $\sin x\ne0$ hence $\cosh y=-x/\sin x$, which could be used in the second equation? Not sure the solutions shall be very explicit, though...

Comment: In general it is not possible to use one root of a function to deduce the existence or location of other roots. Imagine yourself standing on a mountaintop: the existence and location of *that* mountaintop tells you nothing about other mountaintops.

Comment: Alternatively, rewrite as $z=2\pi i k\pm\sin^{-1}(z-i),k\in\Bbb N$